# Can not define part of an array

Tags: arrays, vba, size

A very basic question...
What is the problem with the following rows?

```
Function testfun(arra As Variant)
    arra(2).Value = 5
    testfun = arra
End Function
```

I just want to change one of the values of the array used as an input for the function. I suppose it is related to the size and that it is not defined but I don't know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is `arra` passed as?  What error is raised?

Comment: arra is passed as a range. The error is #VALUE.